# Service Entrance Wire To Drop Splice - 200AMP

Tags: electrical, wiring, nec, meter

I am replacing the old service drop wire from 4AWG to 4/0, as the panel has been upgraded for 200A service.
The service has been shut off at the pole, and I  was able to remove the old service drop with the old meter box.  Pictured are the wire from the pole (top left) and the old service drop wire (bottom right); both 4AWG.
[image]

The bolt connectors seem to be made for a 4 AWG in/out, so they likely wouldn't be able to accommodate the new drop wire being 4/0.  My question is - Would this type of connector work (working under NEC 2017/2020, if code is even applicable here): [https://www.amazon.com/ESGS-4-Easy-Splice-Line-Splice-Connector/dp/B0B37HRV7Q](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B37HRV7Q)

Also, are there better alternatives to the splice linked above (expensive crimping and crimp tools aside)? If this is the best option that doesn't require crimping, it is what it is, just figured I'd ask.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying the power company's wire will be 4/0? If so, I don't think that is correct. Typical wire from their transformer to your main panel will be #4 Copper or #2 Aluminum. Call your power co. and see if they will be replacing the existing #4. I highly doubt it.

Comment: AIUI, you are responsible for running the wire to the mast head. The PoCo is responsible for attaching their wire to yours. Don't forget theirs is **_still hot_** and quite likely fatal if you don't have the correct PPE _and training_ for working with it. I wouldn't touch their wires with a 10' fiberglass pole... IMHO no amount of cash savings is worth my life.

Comment: @FreeMan The PoCo wire is 240V isn't it?  I think "quite likely fatal" is overstating the risk. "Probably not fatal" is how I would put it - but that is still far too high a risk for me to be prepared to touch it.  (I am assuming one is working from a cherry-picker platform or similar - the fall from the top of a ladder caused by a 240V jolt could easily be fatal.)

Comment: The power company's wire is pictured on the top left of the picture, it is 4AWG (#4 aluminum).  My new drop wire will be replacing the wire pictured on the bottom right (pictured is the old wire which is also #4), and the new wire will be 4/0 aluminum.
The power company has disconnected THEIR wire at the pole, so that the top left wire is currently NOT connected to the pole (visually and meter double checked) and enabled me to disconnect MY drop wire from the PoCo's wire.  I asked for a confirmation of my choice of connectors (linked in the OP) from 4 AWG (#4) to 4/0.

Comment: Maybe the shock itself doesn't kill you, @MartinBonnersupportsMonica, but it might knock you off your ladder leading to a fatal fall. Generally not good advice to mess with electricity around hot wires. The OP has clarified that the drop has been disconnected at the pole, but that's not always the case.

Comment: I would ask the power company what they expect/want you to do and supply.  Stuff from amazon is probably not on the list.  Service wires from the pole are usually the power companies property, so they handle all the work/connections.

Comment: @FreeMan I explicitly mentioned being knocked off a ladder.  "Generally not good advice to mess with electricity around hot wires." - I entirely agree.  I just object to people saying "quite likely fatal" when they mean "unlikely to be fatal, but it might be".

Comment: Sorry, @MartinBonnersupportsMonica, I missed seeing that.

Comment: The product is available outside of Amazon from various reputable electric suppliers such as - https://www.platt.com/p/0601286/nsi-tork/easy-splice-4-0-kit/662381168610/nsiesgs40
It's ANSI rated, and while I don't see a UL rating, I would appreciate input related to this particular splice method in question from someone familiar with cut & taps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the electric utility provides their own connector for splicing their conductor to the customer's conductor. I'd expect to install the mast and conductors, then leave the provision and installation of the new splice connector to them.

Comment: Just got off the phone with the utility provider, they have confirmed the above - They will be re-attaching the service wire to the drop.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 4):

Your domain / right-to-touch ends at the weatherhead. You should not be touching the *service drop* wires or the crimps, as they are the exclusive domain of the power company.

Other than the wires coming out of the weatherhead, the only other thing you provide is a strong physical anchor to tie off the service drop wires. (assuming it is not the weatherhead itself).  If the existing anchor is sound and in the right place for the new drop, you can continue it in service.

> I asked for a confirmation of my choice of connectors (linked in the OP) from 4 AWG (#4) to 4/0.

No, those are exactly the crimps that you *don't* touch. The power company will provide those crimps when they re-attach the service drop.  Not your problem, leave it alone.

The power company may, or may not, upgrade the service drop wires now. Often they continue the old ones in service and then simply monitor your usage via the smart meter.  If they see usage patterns that warrant an upgrade, a truck will show up and change them.

When the truck shows up to reconnect you, if you argue the point strongly enough, you might talk them into upgrading your drop at that time. But you really have no reason to care. Smart meters measure voltage too, so they're paying to heat the sky, not you.

Comment: Appreciate the confirmation, Harper.  Won't be touching the drop wires at all.